# ElasticSearch: Is it possible to define Alternate key

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Per documentation _Id is used as primary key. If I have an alternate key in data, is it possible to define one in ElasticSearch and prevent duplicate rows if two records with same alternate key gets inserted? I'm using NEST library client.Index(data); to ingest records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use "path" to point the _id field to the field in your source data that you want to use as a unique id:

```
{
    "sample_mapping" : {
        "_id" : {
            "path" : "your_unique_field"
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html

Comment: Thanks. This is how I did with NEST .Net library:          `code`  var response = client.CreateIndex(c => c
                            .Index("person")
                            .InitializeUsing(settings)
                            .AddMapping<DataMap>( m => m
                                .MapFromAttributes()
                                .IdField(f => f
                                    .Path("key")))
                        );